# Flex- Time Zone Conversion

Tags: apache-flex

How to convert date and time to CDT time Zone in flex4

Regards,
Sushma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Date](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html) object in Flash is always set to the computer's time settings.  If the computer is already in the CDT timezone, then just getting any property from the object will be good.  However, if you want to do a timezone 'conversion' into a timezone that the computer is not set to, you can get the UTC time and offset it like this:

```
var date:Date = new Date();
var timezone:int = -5;
date.hours = date.hoursUTC + timezone;
```

However, you're trying to get the actual CDT time, which only works during the summer in certain areas.  For this, it's impossible for Flash to know exactly when that is UNLESS you code the exceptions (ie. if between this date and that date, do -6, else do -5) and you also need to know the actual location of the user (which is impossible through Flash unless the user gives you that info).

Can I ask why you need to know such a thing?

Comment: Hardcoding the offset assumes that the user is in CDT, in which case no conversion would be necessary. The current offset is available in `Date.timezoneOffset()`, and there are UTC methods available to get local time in UTC.

Comment: erm, I mentioned that already? I even asked him what was his intentions for this code as there may be a better way to do this.  Maybe if you bothered reading first...

Comment: What I read was code that used local date and time and offset it for CDT; that isn't going to work unless the user is at UTC+0. If you set `date` to be UTC, then yes, I agree that your approach and questions are reasonable: getting UTC is not an issue, but getting the Central Time equivalent requires more work (it can be done based on current DST rules but would be applicable only as long as the rules don't change).

Comment: What do you think `date.hours = date.hours + date.timezoneOffset + timezone;` does?  It takes the local hour, removes the offset of the local timezone (so that your hours are now in UTC) then add the CDT offset.  Actually, now that I think about it, I could of just taken the UTC hours from the start.  I need more coffee.  Still, your -1 is unjustified.

Comment: `timezoneOffset` is in minutes, so I think your current solution is better. Now I think the OP's reason for this will determine how much tweaking is necessary: if this is for US residents during business hours, I think that's all you need, but otherwise it may need more code ... if hoursUTC is less than 5, then subtracting the offset for CDT will throw an error, so you'd have to adjust both hours and date in that case.

Comment: We have an updated date and time coming from database which has to be converted to cdt time zone.